# Metaprogramming oracle sql select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's imagine I have a query like the following:

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN ONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN JUST_ONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN ANOTHER_ONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,

  CASE WHEN TWO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN JUST_TWO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
  CASE WHEN ANOTHER_TWO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END

  -- 20 more things like that where changes only columns name
FROM
  SOME_TABLE;
```

As you can see, the only difference between these two groups is that in the first one I use columns that have 'ONE' and in the second the ones that have 'TWO' and I have around 30 groups like this in my actual query so I wonder if there is a way to shorten it somehow?

Comment: Not in plain SQL, but you could try dynamically generating this query

Comment: Can I do that with PL/SQL ? I dont have access to any programming languages.

Comment: PL/SQL = **Procedural Language** / Structured Query Language

Comment: Of course you can do it in PL/SQL procedure by dynamically framing the `SELECT` clause and using the `execute immediate` statement to run the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are different columns, you must explicitly mention them separately in the SELECT list. You cannot do it dynamically in pure **SQL**.

I would suggest, using a good **text editor**, it would hardly take a minute or two to write the entire SQL.

You could use **DECODE** which will have some less syntax instead of **CASE** expression which is verbose.

For example,

```
  DECODE(ONE, 1, 1, 0) AS col1, 
  DECODE(JUST_ONE, 1, 1, 0) AS col2,
  DECODE(ANOTHER_ONE, 1, 1, 0) AS col3,
  DECODE(TWO, 1, 1, 0) AS col4,
  DECODE(JUST_TWO, 1, 1, 0) AS col5,
  DECODE(ANOTHER_TWO, 1, 1, 0) as col6
```

I would suggest to stick to **SQL**, and not use **PL/SQL**. They are not the same, they are different engines. `PL --> Procedural Language`.

But if you insist, then you could use a **cursor for loop** to loop through all the columns in [**DBA|ALL|USER]_TAB_COLS**. You could use a **SYS_REFCURSOR** to see the data. First you will have to build the **dynamic SQL**.

Comment: This answer probably the best way to do it.  But there are a few tricks that can be used to run this query in a single SQL statement.  My answer has an example, although it's a bit over-complicated for this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of dynamically creating query. You can put this in e.g. cursor variable if you want more queries created.

```
select 'SELECT ' || listagg('CASE WHEN '||column_name||' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ' || column_name,',') within group(order by column_name) || ' FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
from cols 
where data_type in ('NUMBER')
and table_name = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME';
```

You can use `COLS` view to get all column names and their datatypes for all your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL metaprogramming is possible by combining Oracle Data Cartridge with the ANY types.

Even using an existing package for metaprogramming, building a query inside a query is complicated and should be avoided when possible.  The other answers are generally better, even though they may require an extra step and are not "pure" SQL.

If you *really* need to do everything in a single SQL statement, try my [open source project, Method4](https://github.com/method5/method4).  After installing it, create a sample schema:

```
create table some_table(
    one number, just_one number, another_one number,
    two number, just_two number, another_two number);

insert into some_table values(1,1,1,2,2,2);
```

Run this query that builds the real SELECT statement based on the data dictionary:

```
select * from table(method4.dynamic_query(
    q'[
        --Find columns that match pattern and aggregate into SELECT list.
        select
            'SELECT'||chr(10)||
            rtrim(listagg('  CASE WHEN '||column_name||' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END '||column_name||',', chr(10))
                within group (order by order_by1, order_by2), ',')||chr(10)||
            'FROM some_table' sql_statement
        from user_tab_columns
        join
        (
            --Column names that might match the pattern [null|JUST_|ANOTHER]SPELLED_NUMBER.
            select prefix||spelled_number possible_column_names
                ,order_by1, order_by2
            from
            (
                --Numbers 1-10.
                select upper(to_char(to_date(level, 'j'), 'jsp')) spelled_number
                    ,level order_by1
                from dual
                --Increase this number up to the maximum possible number.
                connect by level <= 10
            )
            cross join
            (
                --Possible prefixes.
                select null prefix, 1 order_by2 from dual union all
                select 'JUST_' prefix, 2 order_by2 from dual union all
                select 'ANOTHER_' prefix, 3 order_by2 from dual
            )
        ) column_names
            on user_tab_columns.column_name = column_names.possible_column_names
        where table_name = 'SOME_TABLE'
    ]'
));
```

The same query will return different columns based on the table:

```
       ONE   JUST_ONE ANOTHER_ONE        TWO   JUST_TWO ANOTHER_TWO
---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1          1           1          0          0           0
```

That's some seriously complicated coding to avoid typing a few lines.  This is the kind of solution that a manager would dream up when he first hears that hard-coding is always bad.

This literally answers the question about metaprogramming an Oracle SQL SELECT statement.  There are a few rare cases where this approach is a life-saver.  But 99.9% of the time it's better to do things the simple way even if it is a bit less automated.

Comment: +1 Although complicated, but answers the question about metaprogramming. I think it could be minimized using XML solution. Thanks for sharing this https://github.com/jonheller1/method4

Answer (score 0):

The generative approach (in SQL limited with manuall post processing) could be

```
with src as (
select 'ONE' col_name from dual union all
select 'TWO' col_name from dual
)
select 
'CASE WHEN '||col_name||' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,'||chr(10)||
'CASE WHEN JUST_'||col_name||' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,'||chr(10)||
'CASE WHEN ANOTHER_'||col_name||' = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,'||chr(10)
from src;
```

giving

```
CASE WHEN ONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN JUST_ONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN ANOTHER_ONE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,

CASE WHEN TWO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN JUST_TWO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
CASE WHEN ANOTHER_TWO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
```

Note that you provide the list of your column names and gets the expanded syntax.
Typically you need to remove the last delimiter and add the wrapping SELECT frame.