# PL/SQL inside WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

It doesn't work, it is not possible in `WITH` clause ?

```
WITH start1 AS 
(
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE immediate 'Select 1 from dual';
  END;
)
SELECT * FROM start1
```

Comment: You're trying to use a PLSQL block within a SQL piece of code, no matter the WITH. This will not work. What do you need to do?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you on ? I believe that this may be possible with 12c.  See page 9 of this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/new-plsql-in-12c-2372822.pdf.

Comment: It looks like you are using Oracle 12, which allows functions and procedures in the WITH clause. But what you are trying to do here is not clear. `start1` seems to be a procedure (the syntax is wrong anyway); what do you mean by `select * from start1`? What do you mean by selecting from a procedure? That makes no sense.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean - at least tell us what happens, and what you expected. Aside from things already mentioned, your dynamic query won't execute anyway because it isn't selecting *into* anything. But what you seem to be attempting doesn't really make sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use the Oracle 12c feature allowing PL/SQL in a `WITH` clause, you are not using it correctly.

Remember, every SQL statement you submit has to have a well-defined set of columns that it will return.  Keeping that in mind, you'll have two options to accomplish what you are after.

#### Option 1 -- Return a cursor in the SELECT results

This option does not require you to know the rowtype of the dynamic SQL statement, but whoever/whatever consumes your query results will need to fetch and process the cursor.  Like this:

```
with function start1 return sys_refcursor is
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc FOR 'SELECT 1 FROM DUAL';
  RETURN l_rc;
END;
select start1 from dual;

START1           
---------------- 
(Cursor)         

The (cursor) value in the result set is the result set of the dynamic SQL statement (i.e., `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL`).
```

#### Option 2 -- Know and use the rowtype of the dynamic SQL ahead of time

This option requires that you create a object types for the rowtype and a table of the rowtype of the dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rc_rowtype IS OBJECT ( val NUMBER );

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE rc_tabtype IS TABLE OF rc_rowtype;

with function start1 return rc_tabtype is
  l_results rc_tabtype;
  l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN l_rc FOR 'SELECT rc_rowtype(1) FROM DUAL';
  FETCH l_rc BULK COLLECT INTO l_results;
  CLOSE l_rc;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('l_results.COUNT = ' || l_results.count);
  RETURN l_results;
END;
select * FROM table(start1);

VAL                                          
--- 
  1
```

Comment: It is possible to build SQL statements that return a dynamic result set, like in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35077057/409172).  But in practice that's almost never what people want to do.  Unless the OP has some extreme case he should almost certainly use one of your suggestions.